# Jaxrs like marshalling and unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb, jax-rs

I'm working on an light-weight framework for marshalling and unmarshalling data sent to and received from a jaxrs service. I'm using the jaxb marshaller and unmarshaller.

When using the service I notice that it is able to marshal lists of entities by wrapping them into tags with the classname and then a "s" at the end. So a `<customer>` will be wrapped with `<customers>`. Is this something that is implementation specific, or is it in the jaxrs specification?

Also, when creating a jaxrs service you specify what MediaTypes it consumes and produces, like so:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
```

You can also specify `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` which is used on the server when returning String, Long etc.

I would like to perform the exact reverse of what happens on the server side. That is unmarshal what has been mashalled by the service, and marshal data in a way that the service is able to unmarshall. Currently I have this code:

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(<array of classes>);
javax.xml.bind.Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
marshaller.marshal(obj, writer);
String xml = writer.toString();

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
JAXBElement<T> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(reader), clazz);
jaxbElement.getValue();
```

However this code is not able to handle TEXT_PLAIN or lists of the specified classes.